# iptables says it should drop, but I can still connect

Tags: vpn, iptables

Ubuntu 20.04

I use NordVPN and it changes my iptables rules when I connect. Occasionally, I have to delete some rules and create new ones so I can still access other machines on my local network.

This morning it happened again. While I was fixing it, I noticed that I was able to connect to a machine on my local network even though it seems like those packets should have been getting dropped.

In the session shown below, I had just finished reconnecting to NordVPN which caused it to create the first 2 rules in INPUT and OUTPUT. It is using 192.154.196.23 to connect to its server. It also adds the DROP rule after that.

A machine on my local network is at 192.168.1.47. Why am I able to connect to it under the following circumstances? Shouldn't packets going to that address be dropped in this case?

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  192.154.196.23       anywhere            
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.47         anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.154.196.23      
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.1.47
```

I can ping the host. Should this be happening?

```
$ ping 192.168.1.47
PING 192.168.1.47 (192.168.1.47) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.47: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.297 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.47: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.257 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.47: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.298 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.47: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.345 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.47 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3077ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.257/0.299/0.345/0.031 ms
```

Comment: `sudo iptables -L` doesn't tell you the whole story. Try `sudo iptables -xvnL` then you might see some interesting interface information added.

Comment: Yup. I discovered some interesting interface information all right. That explains it. Thanks!